# How to encode a STRING variable into a given code page

Tags: character-encoding, abap, codepages, character-set

I've got a string variable containing a text that I need to encode and write to a file, in `UTF-16LE` code page.

Currently the following code generates a `UTF-8` file and I don't see any option in the statement `OPEN DATASET` to generate the file in `UTF-16LE`.

```
REPORT zmyprogram.

DATA(filename) = `/tmp/myfile`.

OPEN DATASET filename IN TEXT MODE ENCODING DEFAULT FOR OUTPUT.

TRANSFER 'HELLO WORLD' TO filename.

CLOSE DATASET filename.
```

I guess one solution is to first encode the string in memory, then write the encoded bytes to the file.

Generally speaking, how to encode a string of characters into a given code page, in memory?

Answer (score 6):

In the first part, I explain how to encode a string of characters into a given code page (all is done in memory), and in the second part, I explain specifically how to write files to the application server in a given code page.

1. **General way** (all in memory)

If a string of characters (type `STRING`) has to be encoded, the result has to be stored in a string of bytes, which corresponds to the built-in data type `XSTRING`.

There are several possibilities which depend on the ABAP version:

- Since 7.53, use the class [`CL_ABAP_CONV_CODEPAGE`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abencl_abap_conv_codepage.htm):

  > DATA(xstring) = cl_abap_conv_codepage=>create_out( codepage = `UTF-16LE` )->convert( source = `ABCDE` ).
- Since 7.02, use the class [`CL_ABAP_CODEPAGE`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abencl_abap_codepage.htm):

> DATA xstring TYPE xstring.

> xstring = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_to( source = `ABCDE` codepage = `UTF-16LE` ).

- Before 7.02, use the class `CL_ABAP_CONV_OUT_CE` (documentation provided with the class):

  First, instantiate the conversion object, use a SAP code page number instead of the ISO name (list of values shown hereafter):

> DATA: conv TYPE REF TO CL_ABAP_CONV_OUT_CE, xstring TYPE xstring.

> conv = CL_ABAP_CONV_OUT_CE=>CREATE( encoding = '4103' ). "4103 = utf-16le

Then encode the string and retrieve the bytes encoded:

> conv->RESET( ).

> conv->WRITE( data = `ABCDE` ).

> xstring = conv->GET_BUFFER( ).

Eventually, instead of using `RESET`, `WRITE` and `GET_BUFFER`, the method `CONVERT` was added in 6.40 and retroported :

> conv->CONVERT( EXPORTING data = `ABCDE` IMPORTING buffer = xstring ).

With the class `CL_ABAP_CONV_OUT_CE`, you need to use the number of the SAP Code Page, not the ISO name. Here are the most common SAP code pages and their equivalent ISO names:

- 1100: ISO-8859-1
- 1101: US-ASCII
- 1160: Windows-1252 ("ANSI")
- 1401: ISO-8859-2
- 4102: UTF-16BE
- 4103: UTF-16LE
- 4104: UTF-32BE
- 4105: UTF-32LE
- 4110: UTF-8
- Etc. (the possible values are defined in the table `TCP00A`, in lines with column `CPATTRKIND = 'H'`).

2. **Writing a file on the application server in a given code page**

In ABAP, [`OPEN DATASET`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapopen_dataset_mode.htm) can directly specify the target code page, most code pages are supported including `UTF-8`, but not other `UTF` (code pages 41xx) which can be done only by the solution explained in 2.3 below (by first encoding in memory).

- 2.1) `IN TEXT MODE ENCODING ...`

Possible `ENCODING` values:

- `UTF-8`: in this mode, it's possible to add the Byte Order Mark if needed, via the option `WITH BYTE-ORDER MARK`.
- `DEFAULT`: will be UTF-8 in a SAP "Unicode" system (that you can check via the menu System > Status > Unicode System Yes/No), NON-UNICODE otherwise.
- `NON-UNICODE`: will depend on the current ABAP linguistic environment; for language English, it's the character encoding `iso-8859-1`, for language Polish, it's the character encoding `iso-8859-2`, etc. (the equivalences are shown in table `TCP0C`.)

Example in ABAP version 7.52 to write to `UTF-8` with the byte order mark:

```
REPORT zmyprogram.
DATA(filename) = `/tmp/dataset_utf_8`.
OPEN DATASET filename IN TEXT MODE ENCODING UTF-8 WITH BYTE-ORDER MARK FOR OUTPUT.
TRY.
    TRANSFER `Witaj świecie` TO filename.
  CATCH cx_sy_conversion_codepage INTO DATA(lx).
    " Character not supported in language code page
ENDTRY.
CLOSE DATASET filename.
```

Example in ABAP version 7.52 to write to `iso-8859-2` (Polish language here):

```
REPORT zmyprogram.
SET LOCALE LANGUAGE 'L'. " Polish
DATA(filename) = `/tmp/dataset_nonunicode_pl`.
OPEN DATASET filename IN TEXT MODE ENCODING NON-UNICODE FOR OUTPUT.
TRY.
    TRANSFER `Witaj świecie` TO filename.
  CATCH cx_sy_conversion_codepage INTO DATA(lx).
    " Character not supported in language code page
ENDTRY.
CLOSE DATASET filename.
```

- 2.2) `IN LEGACY TEXT MODE CODE PAGE ...`

Use any code page number except code pages 41xx (i.e. `UTF-8` and other `UTF`; see workaround in 2.3 below).

Example in ABAP version 7.52 to write to `iso-8859-2` (code page 1401) :

```
REPORT zmyprogram.
DATA(filename) = `/tmp/dataset_iso_8859_2`.

OPEN DATASET filename IN LEGACY TEXT MODE CODE PAGE '1401' FOR OUTPUT. " iso-8859-2
TRY.
    TRANSFER `Witaj świecie` TO filename.
  CATCH cx_sy_conversion_codepage INTO DATA(lx).
    " Character not supported in language code page
ENDTRY.
CLOSE DATASET filename.
```

- 2.3) `UTF = general way + IN BINARY MODE`

Example in ABAP version 7.52:

```
REPORT zmyprogram.
TRY.
    DATA(xstring) = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_to( source = `Witaj świecie` codepage = `UTF-16LE` ).
  CATCH cx_sy_conversion_codepage INTO DATA(lx).
    " Character not supported in language code page
    BREAK-POINT.
ENDTRY.
DATA(filename) = `/tmp/dataset_utf_16le`.
OPEN DATASET filename IN BINARY MODE FOR OUTPUT.
TRANSFER xstring TO filename.
CLOSE DATASET filename.
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, Sandra! It seems that you intentionally create topic-based SAP wiki pages for common tasks :)

Comment: `Use any code page number except code pages 41xx` btw, where did you find out which codepages are supported for legacy text mode and which are not? I don't see any info in help

Comment: [OPEN DATASET - CODE PAGE cp](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapopen_dataset_code_page.htm): "the code page cp expects a character-like data object that must contain, when the statement is executed, the name of a non-Unicode page from the column CPCODEPAGE in the database table TCP00. **Unicode code pages cannot be specified**."